# Get string distance for a pseudo fuzzy search

Tags: javascript, performance, strings, edit-distance

We are using the following for evaluating strings for a pseudo fuzzy search. Curious if anything sticks out as needing optimization

```
    function getEditDistance(a, b) {
    if (a.length == 0) return b.length;
    if (b.length == 0) return a.length;

    var matrix = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [i];
    }

    var j;
    for (j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) {
        matrix[0][j] = j;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
            if (b.charAt(i - 1) == a.charAt(j - 1)) {
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1,
                    Math.min(matrix[i][j - 1] + 1,
                        matrix[i - 1][j] + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The code becomes 25% faster if we extract values not changed in the loops to variables, but of course it's observable only on large number of repetitions or long strings as tested in Chrome.

```
function getEditDistance(a, b) {
    var lenA = a.length, lenB = b.length;
    if (lenA == 0) return lenB;
    if (lenB == 0) return lenA;

    var matrix = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= lenB; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [i];
    }

    var j, m0 = matrix[0];
    for (j = 0; j <= lenA; j++) {
        m0[j] = j;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= lenB; i++) {
        var m = matrix[i], mPrev = matrix[i - 1];
        var bChar = b.charAt(i - 1);
        for (j = 1; j <= lenA; j++) {
            if (bChar == a.charAt(j - 1)) {
                m[j] = mPrev[j - 1];
            } else {
                m[j] = Math.min(mPrev[j - 1] + 1, Math.min(m[j - 1] + 1, mPrev[j] + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix[lenB][lenA];
}
```

P.S. Replacing `s.charAt(i)` with `s[i]` provides no tangible speedup and is not cross-browser.